# Импорт библиотек с помощью функции eval()

Tags: python, python-import, eval

Вот такую консоль я веду:

```
Здраствуйте, пользователь. Введите свой псевдоним: MrSvinia
Ваш псевдоним: MrSvinia. Вы уверены? +
Ваш псевдоним MrSvinia утверждён. Приятного использования системы "Чарльз".
Введите команду: locate
Вы находитесь на корневой ветке всей системы "Чарльз".
Введите команду: list func
Доступные функции: ['help', 'list func', 'locate', 'start', 'user', 'setting']
Введите команду: user
Введите команду: func list
Доступные функции: ['help', 'list func', 'locate', 'start', 'user', 'setting']
Введите команду: func install
Установленные функции: ['basic-math', 'charles-messendger']
Введите команду: start basic-math
basic-math
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\niels\PycharmProjects\Charles\client\re-main.py", line 46, in <module>
    eval('import ' + command[6:])
  File "<string>", line 1
    import basic-math
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

При таком коде:

```
True_mess = ['+', 'Yes', 'yes', 'True', 'true', 1, '1', True]
False_mess = ['-', 'Not', 'not', 'False', 'false', 0, '0', False]

flag_auth = False

while not flag_auth:
    login = input('Здраствуйте, пользователь. Введите свой псевдоним: ')
    if login:
        if input('Ваш псевдоним: ' + login + '. Вы уверены? ') in True_mess:
            print('Ваш псевдоним ' + login + ' утверждён. Приятного использования системы "Чарльз".')
            break
        else:
            print('Подтверждение не распознано или отклонено.')

del flag_auth

file_inst_func = open('inst_func', 'r')
inst_func = file_inst_func.readlines()
for k in range(len(inst_func) - 1):
    inst_func[k] = inst_func[k][:-1]
file_inst_func.close()

while True:
    func = ['help', 'list func', 'locate', 'start', 'user', 'setting']
    command = input('Введите команду: ')
    if command.find('help') == 0:
        if len(command) == 4:
            print('Справка по базовым командам системы "Чаральз":')
            print('help - выводит справку по базовым командам')
            print('func list - вывод список доступных на данной ветке функций')
            print('up - пытается вернуться по ветке назад')
            print('locate - выводит вашу позицию в дереве команд')
            print('start F  - запускает функцию F')
            print('user info - выводит информацию о сессии')
            print('user editor - запускает редактор информации о пользователе')
            print('setting info - выводит базовые параметры')
            print('setting editor - запускает редактор базовых параметров')
            print('stop (extra) - останавливает действующую функцию. extra - останавливает всю систему.')
    elif command.find('locate') == 0:
        print('Вы находитесь на корневой ветке всей системы "Чарльз".')
    elif command.find('start') == 0:
        print(command[6:])
        if command[6:] in inst_func:
            eval('import ' + command[6:])
            print('Импортирована библиотека', command[:6] + '.')
            eval(command[:6] + '.main()')
            print('Запущена библиотека', command[:6] + '.')
        else:
            print('Данная функция не обнаружена. Пожалуйста, проверьте список установленных функций с помощью "func list".')
    elif command.find('func') == 0:
        if command.find('list') == 5:
            print('Доступные функции:', func)
        elif command.find('install') == 5:
            print('Установленные функции:', inst_func)
        else:
            print('Неизвестный аргумент для команды "func".')

print('Спасибо за использование системы "Чарльз". Всего хорошего,', login + '.')
```

Не понимаю откуда вылезает ошибка синтаксиса. Приветствуются любые решения данной проблемы, в т. ч. иной метод, помимо `eval()`
Если кому-то интересно что это - то объясню. Это универсальная оболочка для любых модулей, кому какие нужны - такие пишет и импортирует. `basic-math` - тестовая библиотека-калькулятор (не готова). Прилагаю на всякий. И так же прилагаю файл `inst_func`.
`basic-math`:

```
def main():
    print('Добро пожаловать в "Базовую математику"!')
    command = input('Введите команду:')
```

`inst_func`:

```
basic-math
charles-messendger
```

В ожидании ответа буду писать `basic-math`.

UPD: допи́сался. Словил такую же ошибку.
Консоль:

```
Добро пожаловать в "Базовую математику"!
Введите команду (basic-math): start k = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\niels\PycharmProjects\Charles\client\basic-math.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(main())
          ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\niels\PycharmProjects\Charles\client\basic-math.py", line 16, in main
    eval(command[6:])
  File "<string>", line 1
    k = []
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Код:

```
def sqrt(number, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('precession', False):
        return round(number ** kwargs.get('degree', 2), kwargs['precession'])
    else:
        return number ** kwargs.get('degree', 2)

def main():
    func = ['help', 'func', 'start', 'stop']
    print('Добро пожаловать в "Базовую математику"!')
    while True:
        command = input('Введите команду (basic-math): ')
        if command.split(' ')[0] in func:
            if command.find('help') == 0:
                print('Документация по basic-math:')
            elif command.find('start') == 0:
                eval(command[6:])
            elif command.find('stop') == 0:
                return 'Спасибо за использование basic-math. Процесс завершён.'
        else:
            print('Команда не распознанна.')

print(main())
```

Comment: А зачем eval, если есть importlib?

Comment: @Александр, то есть если я заменю ```eval('import ' + 'basic-math')``` на ```importlib.__import__(basic-math)```, то всё заработает?

Comment: А `basic-math` - это что вообще?

Comment: @Александр, просто библиотека, которую я для теста создал. Чек UPD.

Comment: можно попробовать использовать `exec`

Comment: и вместо `command.find(...) == 0` можно писать `command.startswith(...)`

Comment: @Danis, а eval() не тоже самое?

Comment: @Danis, к тому же неработает, ошибка таже самая.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование `eval` для динамического импорта модуля - не очень хорошая практика. Это во-первых.

Во-вторых конструкция `import` не позволяет импортировать модули с дефисом в названии, потому у вас и выпадает ошибка синтаксиса

#### Решение:

Начиная с версии 3.1 вы можете импортировать модуль с дефисом в имени с помощью importlib:

```py
import importlib  
foobar = importlib.import_module("basic-math")
```

Подробнее [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

Comment: Это-то хорошо, но зачем тут foobar?

Comment: Просто для примера. Исправил на `basic-math`, как у вас

Comment: Не понял. Можно прямую ссылку на абзац документации данного модуля? Не могу найти.

Comment: Добавил линк на документацию

Comment: спасибо, всё заработало. ```importlib.import_module("basic-math")```. Но я всё равно не понимаю зачем ```foobar =```?

Comment: foobar после импорта будет содержать собственно сам импортируемый модуль. Это просто имя переменной. Можете назвать basic_math вместо foobar. Не суть

Comment: получил ошибку, сейчас напишу в UPD, помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: Не в UPD, в отдельном вопросе, сейчас кину ссылку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1503020/nameerror-name-is-not-defined-в-имортируемо-консольной-функции-при-завершении

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144450/discussion-between--and-mrsvinia).