# Ошибка NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python

NameError: name is not defined в импортируемой консольной функции, при завершении работы импортируемой библиотеки

**ПЕРЕПИСАНО** Консоль:

```
Здраствуйте, пользователь. Введите свой псевдоним: MrSvinia
Ваш псевдоним: MrSvinia. Вы уверены? +
Ваш псевдоним MrSvinia утверждён. Приятного использования системы "Чарльз".
Введите команду: start basic-math
Добро пожаловать в "Базовую математику"!
Введите команду (basic-math): stop
Спасибо за использование basic-math. Процесс завершён.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\niels\PycharmProjects\Charles\client\re-main.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(eval(command[:6] + '.main()'))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'start' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

main:

```
import importlib

True_mess = ['+', 'Yes', 'yes', 'True', 'true', 1, '1', True]
False_mess = ['-', 'Not', 'not', 'False', 'false', 0, '0', False]

flag_auth = False

while not flag_auth:
    login = input('Здраствуйте, пользователь. Введите свой псевдоним: ')
    if login:
        if input('Ваш псевдоним: ' + login + '. Вы уверены? ') in True_mess:
            print('Ваш псевдоним ' + login + ' утверждён. Приятного использования системы "Чарльз".')
            break
        else:
            print('Подтверждение не распознано или отклонено.')

del flag_auth

file_inst_func = open('inst_func', 'r')
inst_func = file_inst_func.readlines()
for k in range(len(inst_func) - 1):
    inst_func[k] = inst_func[k][:-1]
file_inst_func.close()

while True:
    func = ['help', 'list func', 'locate', 'start', 'user', 'setting']
    command = input('Введите команду: ')
    if command.find('help') == 0:
        if len(command) == 4:
            print('Справка по базовым командам системы "Чаральз":')
            print('help - выводит справку по базовым командам')
            print('func list - вывод список доступных на данной ветке функций')
            print('locate - выводит вашу позицию в дереве команд')
            print('start F  - запускает функцию F')
            print('user info - выводит информацию о сессии')
            print('user editor - запускает редактор информации о пользователе')
            print('setting info - выводит базовые параметры')
            print('setting editor - запускает редактор базовых параметров')
            print('stop (extra) - останавливает действующую функцию. extra - останавливает всю систему.')
    elif command.find('locate') == 0:
        print('Вы находитесь на корневой ветке всей системы "Чарльз".')
    elif command.find('start') == 0:
        if command[6:] in inst_func:
            basic_math = importlib.import_module(command[6:])
            print(eval(command[:6] + '.main()'))
        else:
            print('Данная функция не обнаружена. Пожалуйста, проверьте список установленных функций с помощью "func list".')
    elif command.find('func') == 0:
        if command.find('list') == 5:
            print('Доступные функции:', func)
        elif command.find('install') == 5:
            print('Установленные функции:', inst_func)
        else:
            print('Неизвестный аргумент для команды "func".')

print('Спасибо за использование системы "Чарльз". Всего хорошего,', login + '.')
```

basic-math:

```
def sqrt(number, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('precession', False):
        return round(number ** kwargs.get('degree', 2), kwargs['precession'])
    else:
        return number ** (1 / kwargs.get('degree', 2))

def main():
    func = ['help', 'func', 'start', 'stop']
    print('Добро пожаловать в "Базовую математику"!')
    while True:
        command = input('Введите команду (basic-math): ')
        if command.split(' ')[0] in func:
            if command.find('help') == 0:
                print('Документация по basic-math:')
            elif command.find('start') == 0:
                eval(command[6:])
            elif command.find('func list') == 0:
                print('Список функций basic-math:')
                print('sqrt(number, **degree = 2, precession = None) - при "precession = None" вернёт "number ** (1 / degree)"')
            elif command.find('stop') == 0:
                return 'Спасибо за использование basic-math. Процесс завершён.'
        else:
            print('Команда не распознана.')
```

Как починить ошибку?

Comment: может надо `command[6:] + ".main()")`?

Comment: @Danis где именно?

Comment: в строке с ошибкой

Comment: @Danis - ни в коем случае! Она же вызывает функцию main() в basic-math, а не запускает файл!

Comment: К тому же я попробовал на всякий - всё стало ещё хуже.

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Избавьтесь от eval. Вообще. Он тут не нужен.

Comment: @Danis - выпадение в изначальную ветку системы и завершение работы basic-math.

Comment: @Александр, я до******, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
import importlib

True_mess = ['+', 'Yes', 'yes', 'True', 'true', 1, '1', True]
False_mess = ['-', 'Not', 'not', 'False', 'false', 0, '0', False]

flag_auth = False

while not flag_auth:
    login = input('Здраствуйте, пользователь. Введите свой псевдоним: ')
    if login:
        if input('Ваш псевдоним: ' + login + '. Вы уверены? ') in True_mess:
            print('Ваш псевдоним ' + login + ' утверждён. Приятного использования системы "Чарльз".')
            break
        else:
            print('Подтверждение не распознано или отклонено.')

del flag_auth

file_inst_func = open('inst_func', 'r')
inst_func = file_inst_func.readlines()
for k in range(len(inst_func) - 1):
    inst_func[k] = inst_func[k][:-1]
file_inst_func.close()

while True:
    func = ['help', 'list func', 'locate', 'start', 'user', 'setting']
    command = input('Введите команду: ')
    if command.find('help') == 0:
        if len(command) == 4:
            print('Справка по базовым командам системы "Чаральз":')
            print('help - выводит справку по базовым командам')
            print('func list - вывод список доступных на данной ветке функций')
            print('locate - выводит вашу позицию в дереве команд')
            print('start F  - запускает функцию F')
            print('user info - выводит информацию о сессии')
            print('user editor - запускает редактор информации о пользователе')
            print('setting info - выводит базовые параметры')
            print('setting editor - запускает редактор базовых параметров')
            print('stop (extra) - останавливает действующую функцию. extra - останавливает всю систему.')
    elif command.find('locate') == 0:
        print('Вы находитесь на корневой ветке всей системы "Чарльз".')
    elif command.find('start') == 0:
        if command[6:] in inst_func:
            work_lib = importlib.import_module(command[6:])
            print(work_lib.main())
            del work_lib
        else:
            print('Данная функция не обнаружена. Пожалуйста, проверьте список установленных функций с помощью "func list".')
    elif command.find('func') == 0:
        if command.find('list') == 5:
            print('Доступные функции:', func)
        elif command.find('install') == 5:
            print('Установленные функции:', inst_func)
        else:
            print('Неизвестный аргумент для команды "func".')

print('Спасибо за использование системы "Чарльз". Всего хорошего,', login + '.')
```

Спасибо Александру, `eval()` тут не нужен, он ошибку и провоцировал. Теперь всё работает.